Azure storage account can be posted from one azure app service but returns error 500 for another
I have a storage account that is holding media files for our application.
It works for our production application but we are getting an internal server error when trying to post from our testing environment.
The backend that is hosted as an app service is identical for both the production app service and the testing app service. The only large difference I have been able to identify is that the production app service is placed in the same ressource group as the storage account and the testing app service is in another.
The testing environemnt is able to get the media files out with its GET request but not POST.
The frontend is hosted as static web apps.
I expect that it is a problem with getting the role assignment correct.
view of the roles for each app service
The app services have roles assigned via their managed identities.
The network settings for the storage account have been set to enabled from all networks and internet routing while I have been debugging.

Enable logstream to get the detailed error.Are you able to access the app locally ?
